# How to right align text of UISearchbar in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

Could you tell me how to right align UISearchbar text in iOS 7? , I was using this in iOS6 but now it does not work in iOS7:

```
//hacking search bar
UITextField *searchField;
for (UIView *subview in self.searchBar.subviews)
{

       if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        searchField = (UITextField *)subview;
        break;
    }
}
if (searchField) {
    searchField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this cannot be done safely without completely re-implementing the class from scratch, as text alignment is adjusted by the internals of the object's code when the user begins and finishes editing.

The closest thing to what you want to do would be to use the three position adjustments to shift the text horizontally, but this doesn't affect alignment, only absolute position, and even then only when the user is typing.

If you want to try this, look up searchTestPositionAdjustment, setPositionAdjustment:forSearchBarIcon:, and searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment. I don't think it will be of much use to you though.

-Ash

Answer (score 1):

It's too late, but if anyone is still wondering the solution, then you can follow this.

```
UITextField *searchTextField = [searchBarController.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
```

You can get the search field using above code. Now simply use the properties you want to use, like.

```
searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
searchTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution to this problem. It's a bit hacky and not very neat, but it does the trick.

Since `UISearchBar` itself does not allow you to edit the placeholder, I've set a `UITextField` underneath it and disabled it from any touches by doing this:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{

  if([touch.view isDescendantOfView:self.placeHolderTextField]){
    return NO;
  }

  return YES;
}
```

Note: don't forget to include `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` in your .h file.
If this doesn't work however, you can always use `[self.view sendSubViewToBack:self.placeholderTextField];`

Next on, I've just set events on which I want to display the placeholder and when not. 
In the `viewDidLoad`, I'm just calling `self.placeHolderTextFiew.placeholder = @"search"`

And in

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if(searchText.length > 0){
      self.placeHolderTextfield.placeholder = @"";
    }  else{
       self.placeHolderTextfield.placeholder = @"search";
    }
}
```

Note again: Make sure to include `<UISearchBarDelegate>` in your .h file in order for this to work.

I am using a `tableView` as well, so when the method `DidSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called, I'm also setting the placeholder to an empty string.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

you can try like this also..
searchbar.placeholder = @"Hai.. whitespace                                                  ";

Comment: First off, that would push the text 'Hai' to the left, not the right. Secondly, you'd never be able to get it exactly right because the width of the 'space' character is more than one pixel. Thirdly, you'd have to dynamically add and remove spaces as the user typed, which would result in the text jiggling back and forth in an unsightly fashion. Finally, it would only affect the placeholder text. As soon as the user started typing into the field, the text would left-align itself.

Comment: he is asking for right align not left align and placeholder is only for hint not real text.

Answer (score -2):

way to set text right align

searchbar->attribute inspector->search text->custom offset->horizontal(set as per requirement)

Answer (score -3):

After playing with subviews of UISearchBar I found this solution, it works for iOS 6 and iOS 7

```
//hacking search bar
UITextField *searchField;
for (UIView *subview in self.searchBar.subviews)
{

    //this will work in iOS 7
    for (id sub in subview.subviews) {
        if([NSStringFromClass([sub class]) isEqualToString:@"UISearchBarTextField"])
        {
            [sub setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
        }
    }
    //this will work for less than iOS 7
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        searchField = (UITextField *)subview;
        break;
    }
}
//for less than iOS 7
if (searchField) {
    searchField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
}
```

Comment: That's because the UISearchBarTextField isn't a direct subview of the search bar. You can retrieve it and set its right text alignment by walking up the hierarchy with a recursive search for the class, but this is bad practice. If Apple changes the class view hierarchy again it could break. In any case, it will only set alignment for the text while it's being entered. The placeholder will still be centred, and the icon will still be left-aligned.

Comment: I did it recursively before fetching subviews then subviews of the subviews until I reached the textView. But as @Ash said it may break in the future.