# On iOS 7 UISearchBar left align placeholder text?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

On iOS 7 UISearchBar the placeholder text is centred and I want to disable that and make it always stick to the left like it was before.

[image]

There is a private method setCenterPlaceholder, on the diffs and calling this with a BOOL will make the trip. https://gist.github.com/nscoding/7220368

**Header file**

```
@interface NSCodingSearchBar : UISearchBar

// Default by the system is YES.
// https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UISearchBar.h
@property (nonatomic, assign, setter = setHasCentredPlaceholder:) BOOL hasCentredPlaceholder;

@end
```

**Implementation file**

```
#import "NSCodingSearchBar.h"


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


@implementation NSCodingSearchBar


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma mark - Initializers
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {
        self.hasCentredPlaceholder = YES;
    }

    return self;
}


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma mark - Methods
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)setHasCentredPlaceholder:(BOOL)hasCentredPlaceholder
{
    _hasCentredPlaceholder = hasCentredPlaceholder;

    SEL centerSelector = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"setCenter", @"Placeholder:"]);
    if ([self respondsToSelector:centerSelector])
    {
        NSMethodSignature *signature = [[UISearchBar class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:centerSelector];
        NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
        [invocation setTarget:self];
        [invocation setSelector:centerSelector];
        [invocation setArgument:&_hasCentredPlaceholder atIndex:2];
        [invocation invoke];
    }

}


@end
```

I am wondering if there is any other, not "Hacky way" that does the same thing.

Comment: It's preferable if you include the code in the question, instead of just linking to it.

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19555305/2155985

Comment: I don't think this a good idea. You should try and stick with the standards as much as possible.

Comment: please check my answer ons this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25827025/3746156

Answer (score 3):

To get left alignment of the placeholder in iOS7 you can add white spaces to the end of your placeholder string. For example:

```
_searchBar.placeholder = @"Search                  ";
```

Note that it is should be done separately for each search bar and each language.

One could try to write automatic calculation of needed spaces after text for any language but it seems impossible to read the size of searchBar's textField frame

```
<UISearchBarTextField: 0x1349c160; frame = (0 0; 0 0);
```

Comment: What's wrong? It really works and simply though maybe looks silly.

Comment: I used this my self. Now, how to add those white spaces?

Comment: You can type ordinary spaces like in example above after h and before ".
Or you can write utf-8 codes of different white spaces as \uXXXX

Comment: iOS 8 will trim the whitespace around the placeholder.

Comment: @Pwner - you can add a `\u200B` character to the end of the search string - this is an invisible character that is not considered white space. Therefore it will still be invisible, but it will not get trimmed off.

Comment: What about different screen size?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it with a `UISearchBar` but this works with a `UITextField`. I Subclassed it and overrode `leftViewRectForBounds:`, `textRectForBounds:` and `editingRectForBounds:`, here is the code:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
  CGRect inset = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + kLeftTextPadding,
                        bounds.origin.y,
                        bounds.size.width - kLeftTextPadding,
                        bounds.size.height);
  return inset;
}
```

Hope it helps.