# How to keep the UISearchBar's placeholder left-aligned

Tags: ios

I find the iOS system(7.0+) keep the placeholder of UISearchBar center-aligned,but left-aligned in 6.0- version. I want to keep UISearchBar's placeholder left-aligned in all versions of iOS. then,how can I handle with it?

I attempt to append whitespace character to the UISearchBar's placeHolder, It seems to  resolve the problem, But I want to know whether exist elegant method to handle this problem. Is there god can teach me to end the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666739/on-ios-7-uisearchbar-left-align-placeholder-text

Comment: the problem has been resolved perfectly via the link provided by Anbu.Karthik, thanks for guiding!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *subView in self.subviews){
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *text = (UITextField*)subView;
            text.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            text.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
        }
    }
```