# Search Bar Styles Change In Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I trying to change the Search Bar Display style in Xamarin IOS.
But i couldn't make it properly.
Please find the below images.

Default Search bar

[image: Default Search Bar In Xamarin IOS]

Required Search bar

[image]

I want to display search bar in required styles.
I tried to remove the gray color and border from default search bar, but i couldn't make it.

Can any one suggest me, How to change the default search bar style to required search bar style.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to left align the placeholder text, but part of what you are looking for might be achieved by setting the search bar style:

`searchBar.SearchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal;`

[image: UISearchBarStyle.Minimal]

Otherwise you will have to not use the built in search bar but create your own view. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20384021/2913599

where the accepted answer is: "Don't use a UISearchBar if you need to do these kinds of customizations. You'll have to make your own using a UITextField and a UIImageView, and responding to the delegate calls."

However that thread has some other ideas about aligning the placeholder text to the left. The only one I could get to work was to add space padding to the placeholder text, e.g.:

`searchBar.Placeholder = "Search                               ";`

How many spaces you need to pad with of course depends in the search bar width. With the added space padding I got this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set `BackgroundColor` property to `Transparent`.